# Can not access private field through public get via proxy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

When getting Data from a VueX Module via Getter the Object is wrapped with a Proxy that throws following error:

> TypeError: attempted to get private field on non-instance

when trying to read a private property with a public getter.

```
class Example {
  #privateField;

  get privateField() {
    return this.#privateField;
  }
}
```

```
computed(){
  getInfoForSpecificItem() {
    const arrayOfInstantiatedExamples = this.$store.getters['getArrayOfInstantiatedExamples'];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfInstantiatedExamples.length; i += 1) {
      // trying to access it in this condition throws the error since the Object
      // has been wrapped with a Proxy coming from Vue (I guess)
      if (arrayOfInstantiatedExamples[i].privateField === 'something') {
        // does something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why am I not able to read the property, and how can I create an instance from the proxy target.
logging the Proxy Object reveals, that the target has all information, yet trying to read it via getter doesn't work.

Are there any other options than making the fields public?

Comment: This isn't how classes and methods are done in Javascript.

Comment: @Hackinet But it seems to be like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) . What do you mean?

Comment: The thing you are following is just the prototype of a getter method. It's not how's it's done. Try this link, it will makes things clear: https://javascript.info/class

Comment: Instead of making it private maybe you should declare it protected.
Check this should be useful [link](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/typescript/access-modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is quite incorrect; I'm not 100% sure it was at the time of writing but I think even then, it was.

#fieldName is indeed valid syntax; it specifies that a field is private in JS classes.

The caveat here is that you must specify any private fields inside the class initializer, as you have done. You can't, however, redefine a field with the same name as a getter function; however, it doesn't appear that you're doing that (as then the getter function would be `get #fieldName()`.

Your class should work when not wrapped in a proxy, and I'm sure you've seen that behavior.

When you wrap it in a Proxy, however, the object has now become a 'Proxy object' wrapping your 'myObject', meaning it is defined by the Proxy Class and not your class - this has the effect that the object you are referencing indeed does *not* have that #myPrivate field defined (as the only way that would happen is if the built in Proxy class has such a #myPrivate field in it's class initializer defined *or* if you had extended the internal Proxy class and defined a #myPrivate field in the extended classes initializer area and even *if* it was defined this way, it would be a wholly *different* #myPrivate variable than the one defined in the class you are proxying).

It may seem slightly confusing as it's not the same behavior one would expect when using standard (public) fields/properties on an object. When you Proxy an object (or even extend a class and instantiate a new object), it becomes a new defined by *that* class (either Proxy or your extended class) - you can *only* access *private* #myPrivate fields *inside* the class or instance of a class that defined them. This is different from public fields/properties where they're not 'hidden' in this way and you can access them fine, even when extending a class you're able to call methods with `super.myMethod()` if that method was overwritten in the extending class.

The reasoning behind this is the reason #privateFields exist in the first place. If anyone could Proxy or extend a class and access it's #privateFields, then they wouldn't be that private! Imagine a 3rd party service whose source has a class with private fields; one of those private fields gets filled out with some kind of private value like a token/key/etc, say #myLicenseToken; whether you extend or Proxy the provider's class, your class is unable to access #myLicenseToken. This isn't a great example though as I explain below:

I should note that while OTOH I can't think of any real workarounds or hacks in *code* to get around this, that the #privateFields feature is more about information hiding, for example for implementation purposes, such as preventing namespace collisions or making it clear what methods or properties/values are available to a developer and which ones are used for internal implementation that a developer either shouldn't be concerned with or shouldn't even really touch as it could break stuff. Generally, JavaScript is an interpreted language, thus even if code is provided in an obfuscated way or even as compiled bytecode, it's not impossible for one to figure out and duplicate what a function is doing to define such a private value **nor will it prevent someone from inspecting the value in memory or using the inspector/debugger**!

Proxy traps, from what I can tell, will also not see accesses to private values.

One thing you can do instead and hopefully this works for you, is assign the proxy on the class *itself* and use both a trap and standard getter/setter, which kind of allows trapping private values, as shown here:

```js
class myClass {
    #myPrivateField = 'private';

    constructor() {
        return new Proxy(this,this);
    }

    get myPrivateField() {
        console.log(`Standard Getter for myPrivateField -> ${this.#myPrivateField}`);
        return this.#myPrivateField;
    }

    set myPrivateField(value) {
        console.log(`Standard Setter for myPrivateField -> ${this.#myPrivateField} -> ${value}`);
        this.#myPrivateField = value;
    }

    get(target,prop) {
        console.log(`Proxy Trapped Get for ${prop} -> ${this[prop]}`);
        return this[prop];
    }

    set(target,prop,value) {
        console.log(`Proxy Trapped Set for ${prop} -> ${value}`);
        this[prop] = value;
        return true;
    }
}

console.log('Test Start..');

let x = new myClass();

console.log("accessing #myPrivateField on object 'x'", x.myPrivateField);
console.log("about to set #myPrivateField on object 'x'");
x.myPrivateField = 'test';
console.log("accessing #myPrivateField on object 'x'",x.myPrivateField);
```

output:

```
Test Start..
Standard Getter for myPrivateField -> private
Proxy Trapped Get for myPrivateField -> private
Standard Getter for myPrivateField -> private
accessing #myPrivateField on object 'x' private
about to set #myPrivateField on object 'x'
Proxy Trapped Set for myPrivateField -> test
Standard Setter for myPrivateField -> private -> test
Standard Getter for myPrivateField -> test
Proxy Trapped Get for myPrivateField -> test
Standard Getter for myPrivateField -> test
accessing #myPrivateField on object 'x' test
```

This works because the class Proxy uses is the *same* class your private #myPrivate fields are defined on, but still doesn't allow accessing #myPrivate fields from a different class or object instance.

You could also do this:

```js
class myClass {
    #myPrivateField = 'private';

    constructor() {
        return new Proxy(this,this);
    }

    get(target,prop) {
        let val;
        if (prop == '$myPrivateField') {
            val = this.#myPrivateField;
        } else {
            val = this[prop];
        }

        console.log(`Proxy Trapped Get for ${prop} -> ${val}`);

        return val;
    }

    set(target,prop,value) {
        let old;

        if (prop = '$myPrivateField') {
            old = this.#myPrivateField;
            this.#myPrivateField = value;
        } else {
            old = this[prop];
            this[prop] = value;
        }

        console.log(`Proxy Trapped Set for ${prop} -> ${value} (was: ${old})`);
        return true;
    }
}

console.log('Test Start..');

let x = new myClass();

console.log(`accessing #myPrivateField on object 'x'`, x.$myPrivateField);
console.log(`about to set #myPrivateField on object 'x'`);
x.$myPrivateField = 'test';
console.log(`accessing #myPrivateField on object 'x'`,x.$myPrivateField);
```

output:

```
Test Start..
Proxy Trapped Get for $myPrivateField -> private
accessing #myPrivateField on object 'x' private
about to set #myPrivateField on object 'x'
Proxy Trapped Set for $myPrivateField -> test (was: private)
Proxy Trapped Get for $myPrivateField -> test
accessing #myPrivateField on object 'x' test
```

However, you must specify the property names directly in the getter/setter; this you can't just do something like the following to access any private value if the accessor starts with '$':

```js
// ...
    get(target,prop) {
        let val;
        if (prop.startsWith('$')) {
            val = this[`#${prop}`];
        } else {
            val = this[prop]
        }

        console.log(`Proxy Trapped Get for ${prop} -> ${val}`);

        return val;
    }
// ...

console.log(x.$myPrivateField);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't proper fix for this case, and not planned to fix.

Refer these articles:

- https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/8149#issuecomment-1521009456
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#no_private_property_forwarding

Answer (score -1):

You are defining a `class` not a `function`. So remove the parentheses`()`.

```
class Example {
```

You cannot define variable with `#`. Only `$` and `_` are allowed to use in a variable. So replace `#` with `$` like this `$privateField;`

Classes are blueprints, not a valid object. First make an object from this class.

```
const proxyWrappedExample = new Example;
```

After you log this then you can avoid the error but it logs `undefined`.

Your code should look like

```
class Example {
  $privateField = 'something';

  get privateField() {
    return this.$privateField;
  }
}

const proxyWrappedExample = new Example;

// I receive the Object (which has been instantiated earlier) wrapped in a proxy Object. 
// Trying to access the property throws the error.
// e.g.:

console.log(proxyWrappedExample.privateField); // 'something'
```

`$privateField` without any value will look like following.

```
class Example {
  $privateField;

  get privateField() {
    return this.$privateField;
  }
}

const proxyWrappedExample = new Example;

// I receive the Object (which has been instantiated earlier) wrapped in a proxy Object. 
// Trying to access the property throws the error.
// e.g.:

console.log(proxyWrappedExample.privateField); // 'undefined'
```

Comment: the parentheses were a typo, i edited it. 

I think you didn't understand my question. 
I have an instantiated Object of Class Example, but it is wrapped with a Proxy. 
Without the wrapping I can access it without a problem, but as soon as the proxy comes into play, I get the error.

Comment: The problem with declaring `$privateField;` within the class body is that it is not *"private"*. It is / it becomes a public accessible property of any `Example` instance. The OP'S syntax was chosen intentionally since the OP's code makes use of [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).